# Working with non-clustered index on nvarchar(50) column

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, ddl

I have been tasked at looking at an MSSQL db to see if I can enhance performance anywhere. Most of the DB has clustered-indexes using the standard ID Identity primary key field.

In the area I am concerned about I have found where two tables are not linked via a standard primary key -> foreign key relationship. Instead there is an nvarchar(50) field that corresponds in both tables as the contents are the same. So an inner join can be done without a concrete relationship. Here a non-clustered index has been created.

I have queried why we are not doing it the same way as everywhere else in the DB, and explained that I thought this could be where things are being significantly slowed down. I have been told that it won't be an issue because there is a non-clustered index on the field in question. So I should look elsewhere.

So I thought I would ask what people think. Will a non-clustered index, setup on an nvarchar(50) column that is used to join two tables (the two tables in question have non concrete relationship between each other) cause any performance issues, especially when comparing to a primary key, system generated clustered-index.

Would be grateful for any advise here.

Comment: This question is way too vague, do you have an execution plan for the query you think is going slow?

Comment: Why don't you just test it by copying the table and setting indexes on integer columns and define 'normal' relationships and run the same queries you are running here. Include the actual execution plans and set statistics io, time on.

Comment: To enhance performance of something you got to find something with bad performance first. So called bottlenecks. There are scripts in the internet for finding "slow running queries", there are `profiler`, `wait stats` and known issues (inside your company) about slow-running functionality. Looking at the tables and indexing everything around _for the case_ - is not the way of making something better.

Comment: nvarchar(50) datatype on column can be used as primary/foreign key column